# Specify the order of checking constraints in an SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I'm working with SQL Server 2012. I have a table `MyTable` with a reasonable number of indices. The table has about 10 million records and 20 columns:

```
 Field1, Field2, ..., Field20.
```

I'm writing a query to the table with 15 constraints to the fields:

```
select * 
from MyTable 
where Field1 = Value1 and Field2 = Value2 and... Field15 = Value15
```

The problem is that if I put all the 15 constraints, then the query takes forever even though it is supposed to return only about ~50 records. On the contrary, if I put up to any five constrains, then the query is executed in a couple of seconds and returns some ~300 records (i.e., a very small set). So it becomes pretty fast to apply to this superset those 10 filters that were left: it can be applied either on the client side C# code or be inserted in a temporary table on the server side.

My question is whether there is any way to explicitly tell to the SQL Server how and in which sequence to apply the constraints specified in the `WHERE` clause? E.g., when the SQL Server processes the list of constraints it should first process the constraints on the fields Field1, Field3, and Field7 and only then start applying other filters to the resulted set.

On one hand, it is clear that I'm free to use T-SQL to explicitly store/save the results of all the intermediary steps of the filtering process and there is nothing bad to rely on the client side if it increases the overall performance. But on another hand, I think that I'm facing a fairly common situation and I believe there should be special means of addressing this problem.

Thanks for any direction!

UPDATE: it seems that the suggestion of marc_s to use CTE (Common Table Expression) is what I've been looking for.

Comment: Can you indicate (1) what fields are in your where clause (2) what indexes are on the table (3) any partitions on the table and (4) provide the execution plan of the query with all 15 conditions and (5) provide the execution plan of the query with fewer than all conditions, where it is running well

Comment: There's no way to "prioritize" conditions in your `WHERE` clause - if you need to make sure to have certain conditions checked first, you'll need to do a subquery with just those conditions, and wrap this up in a CTE (Common Table Expression) or store the results into a temp table to do further processing on them in subsequent steps

Comment: outside @marc_s excellent advice, take a look at the execution plan and the server statistics (IO and TIME) and figure out which of the conditions actually do take the time. Also remember you might be running into parameter sniffing issues and might be better off making multiple smaller/specialized procedure calls instead of one-size-fits-all query

Comment: @marc_s it seems that CTE is exactly what I needed! Thanks! I don't like to explicitly insert results into a temp table cause it may eat a lot of time. I expected something like what CTE offers.

Comment: CTEs aren't at all guaranteed to do this. The predicates can get pushed around the plan. It is unlikely that you have diagnosed the issue correctly anyway. There must be some other differences in the plans.

Comment: You state there are a "reasonable number of indices". Adding conditions to a query can make SQL Server choose another index to resolve the query. Adding a column or two to the index being used in the query having 5 conditions might solve the root cause of your problem. Forcing SQL server to apply 5 conditions first and the rest later sounds like bandaid solution to me.

Comment: @MWillemse It is indeed a bandaid solution. I'm given a rigid database, I have no control over it. So I can't really modify whatever architecture it has.

Answer (score 0):

you told:

> if I put up to any five constrains, then the query is executed in a
>   couple of seconds

so I prefer to try with breaking the conditions in where clause (5th-5th) using nested selects, also bring the name of columns instead of using `*` because it does not pays attention to indexes:

```
select Field1, Field2, ..., Field20 from
 (select Field1, Field2, ..., Field20 from
  (select Field1, Field2, ..., Field20 
   from MyTable 
   where Field1 = Value1 and Field2 = Value2 and... Field5 = Value5)
  where Field6 = Value6 and Field7 = Value7 and... Field10 = Value10)
 where Field11 = Value11 and Field12 = Value12 and... Field15 = Value15
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing the suggestion! Actually, it was one of my first steps when I faced the problem and unfortunately in my case it didn't help. More to say, in many cases the execution plan was exactly the same as in the original "undivided" query. Also, I tried forming a subquery as a view and then apply additional  constraints to the view - the result was pretty much the same as in the case of a divided query.

Comment: you are welcome, for me sometimes dividing the query with bringing the most limiting constrains to most inner query solved such these problems that's why I posted this answer, anyway I hope you'll fix it soon, good luck

Comment: I'm really sorry for those who down votes answers without any comment